# Google Web Fonts displaying poorly on Chrome Mac

Tags: css, google-chrome, webfonts, google-webfonts, text-rendering

I'm using Google Web Fonts on a site and it's rendering pretty poorly in Chrome Mac Version 19.0.1084.52. This only seems to be an issue when `font-weight: 700 (bold);` is used. Here is a screenshot comparison of my site and how it renders on the Google Web Fonts site:
http://cl.ly/0Q3m2F1X0f3S3I190U2n

It's the same size and weight yet it's not nearly as clean and clear on my site.
Also using `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;`
Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!